# How to parse out {'value__avg': 46.26524716693248} 'value_avg' when using aggregate(Avg()) in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am using django here is my model:

```
 class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    altitude = models.IntegerField(max_length=10000)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area) + ':' + str(self.name)
#measurement.id value date location
class Measurement(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.FloatField(max_length=50)
    data = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')

    def __str__(self):
       return "measurement@"+str(Location.objects.filter(id=self.id))
```

My HTML page is showing {'value__avg': 46.26524716693248} when it should just show 46.265.

Heres my function:

```
@property
def average_measurement(self):
    locations = Location.objects.filter(area__name=self.name)
    return Measurement.objects.filter(location__in=locations).aggregate(Avg('value'))
```

so how do I get the ugly part out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) returns a *dictionary* where the key is combined from the grouping keys and grouping function name, you can just get the value by key:

```
return Measurement.objects.filter(location__in=locations).aggregate(Avg('value'))["value__avg"]
```

Or, if needed, you can also do that in the template using the dot-notation:

```
{{ obj.average_measurement.value__avg }}
```

---

You can also preset the key name with your own value:

```
return Measurement.objects.filter(location__in=locations).aggregate(my_average=Avg('value'))
```

Then, you would access it as:

```
{{ obj.average_measurement.my_average }}
```

Comment: You sir are the best! Hahaha thank you so much I looked through so many docs I could not find a way to get it to work. Lol thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

That's not the ugly part, it's expected output and you need to understand what does the output mean. When you do django Aggregation, it returns a dictionary-like object with your aggregation criteria as keys and results as values.

What you need to do is to access it like a dictionary in template to extract the values:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.value__avg|floatformat:3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Check django doc about [what is the lookup sequence for dot in template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#variables).

Also checkout django doc about [aggreate function call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset).

Also checkout django doc about [floatformat template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat).

Comment: Thank you so much I used the floatformat for the html.view file at the end.  I used @alecxe part as well
return Measurement.objects.filter(location__in=locations).aggregate(Avg('value'))["value__avg"]

thank you for all the help made my day!